# How often does foliage spawn?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Everyday there seems to be some new trees, bushes, mushroom patches and stumps appearing. I'm wondering if their spawning is completely random or if there is a time gap for foliage spawning.

Comment: @Timelord64 clearly not because the initial part of the question was about foliage not gem boxes, I want to know about foliage

Comment: To quote; How often does foilage **& gem boxes** spawn?. Its only a half duplicate, because you ask two things. That in itself is a potential issue

Comment: @Timelord64 to bad the initial question was about foliage and not gem boxes then, plus it doesn't even have an answer, leave my posts alone I don't like your constant input

Answer (score 10):

From the [wiki](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Obstacles):

> Vegetation re-spawns at a rate of **one item per eight hours**, except if all the spaces in your village are totally filled.

There can be a maximum of 40 obstacles at any one time, foliage, or vegetation, is counted as an obstacle, as are rocks, tombstones, gem boxes and special obstacles (Xmas or Halloween themed generally).

The chance of a certain vegetation spawning is as follows:

- Mushroom - 10%
- Bush - 20%
- Trunk (1) - 10%
- Trunk (2) - 10%
- Trunk (Fallen) - 20%
- Tree (Small) - 20%
- Tree (Medium) - 5%
- Tree (Large) - 5%

Note that rocks will not naturally spawn and tombstones will only be created when a troop dies. In addition special obstacles (Gem Boxes and other seasonal obstacles such as the Xmas Tree and the Halloween Cauldron) will ignore the 1 tile buffer around buildings and will spawn in any 2x2 space in the village.

Answer (score 3):

I believe It is random from my clash experiences.

It may help to know there is a pattern for gem yields from clearing foliage, as seen on the [wiki](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Obstacles):

> Each obstacle that is removed will yield 0-6 Gems. The distribution is not random and follows the following repeating sequence: 6, 0, 4, 2, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 5, 1, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0. This means on average, each obstacle cleared yields 2 Gems. This pattern does not include the 25 gems yielded from the Gem Box, or the holiday themed obstacles like the Halloween